# Enable port access container through dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a container running a AMQP server and it can be accessed on a tcp port let's say 5555. I have an application running on the same host and can access it successfully on port 5555. However I'm now trying to build a container for that app and somehow it can't access port 5555 anymore.

Doing standard http requests work and so the container can access the internet it just it seems it can't access specific ports. I'm assuming that needs to be configured in the dockerfile. I have tried EXPOSE but reading the documentation that's not what I want and I'm not sure what needs to be done to make it happen.

For reference this is my dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1.0-preview1-runtime
WORKDIR .
COPY out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test.dll"]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: can you post your `docker run` command?

Comment: docker run -it --rm test

Comment: no `-p` or `--expose`? check the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

Comment: That's essentially the bit I don't get. Is -p or --expose used to open a connection on that port as well? I want to be able to establish a TCP on 5555 from my container into another container which I know it works when running the app "outside" docker. Can that then be achieved using -p / --expose? I'm going to try that anyway

Comment: I found what the problem was which is completely unrelated. My configuration was pointing to localhost:5555 which wouldn't be anymore when running the app inside the container. Changing that to the Gateway (172.2.0.1:5555) fixed the problem.